# Error in matrix

Tags: amsmath, matrices

In the following matrix

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
    \begin{bmatrix}
        a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} & a_{14} & a_{15} & a_{16} & 0     & \cdots & 0      &        &         &        & \\
        a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} & a_{24} & a_{25} & a_{26} & 0     & \cdots & 0      &        &         &        & \\
        a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33} & a_{34} & a_{35} & a_{36} & 0     & \cdots & 0      &        &         &        & \\
        a_{41} & a_{42} & a_{43} & a_{44} & a_{45} & a_{46} & 0     & \cdots & 0      &        &         &        & \\
        0      & 0      & 0      & 1/24   & -9/8   & 9/8    & -1/24 & 0      & \cdots &        &         &        & \\
        \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & 0      & 1/24   & -9/8   & 9/8   & -1/24  & 0      & \cdots &         &        & \\
               &        &        & \vdots & 0      & 1/24   & -9/8  & 9/8    & -1/24  & 0      & \cdots  &        & \\
               &        &        &        & \vdots & 0      & 1/24  & -9/8   & 9/8    & -1/24  & 0       & \cdots & \\
               &        &        &        &        & \vdots & 0     & \ddots & 0      &        &         &        &
    \end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

I'm receiving the message

```
! Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr.
<recently read> \endtemplate 

l.17 \end{align}
```

Cannot understand why, I have checked all `&` and they all match, tried to add $0$ in empty cells, but same error.

Comment: Yes proabably a duplicate, I didn't know that. Tried to search by the error but nothing was related to that. I will check and let you know.

Comment: The last matrix line does not have '\\' termination...

Comment: @JLeonV.: ...nor does it need one.